# Why are there no users with ID 6-17

Tags: support, profile-page, users

I was just looking at some of the founder users of stack overflow, but found that:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/(6-16) some of them 
produce a page not found error. Why are these positions empty? Are user ID's not needed to be in serial?

Comment: Deleted users. And why would they need to be consecutive anyway?

Comment: That is what I feel.. I could not obviously think that stack exchange awards random ids to its users!

Comment: Why were these initial users deleted? They would have been truly active users.. Right?

Comment: SO opened 7 years ago. Things change, people change. Non-consecutive doesn't necessarily mean random. Keeping consecutive IDs is more expensive than allowing gaps.

Comment: They were probably testing the registration mechanism after going live and created a bunch of dummy users in the process...!?

Comment: You are number 6.

Comment: @bmargulies I AM NOT A NUMBER, I AM A FREE MAN!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those accounts were simply deleted; we don't keep *all* user accounts. Those accounts in the low ids were mostly test accounts and moderators delete the accounts of spammers and trolls. In addition sometimes people delete their own accounts (or request that they are deleted if they cannot do this themselves).

There is no need to reuse those ids, especially if there is a chance that whomever got the re-used id could then be confused with the previous 'owner' of that id.

Comment: Considering that only the number is ever used to identify the account, that's less a chance than a certainty...

Comment: How does StackOverflow generate unique sequential user IDs considering that they certainly have a distributed database? Do they have a centralized service and all clients request a user ID when a new user account is created? If so, how does this service handle a huge amount of requests if they happen all at the same time? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix: it's Microsof SQL Server, and it is *not* a distributed database (though it *is* replicated to a fail-over).

Comment: OK, so you they use multiple "master" servers which accept the writing operations or is there a single master instance which accepts all the writes and then updates its slaves? But again, if there is a single master, how does it handle all the heavy load if there is a lot of traffic at the same time? This also relates to SO posts (questions and answers), they also have sequential/consecutive IDs

Comment: @tonix: sorry, this is not my field of expertise nor is this really relevant to this question or answer.

Comment: @tonix: the engineers behind Stack make regular blog posts on their work, such as [Nick Craver's architecture overview](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) and the main DBA [Taryn Pratt](https://www.tarynpivots.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the links!