# How does Stack Overflow generate the user id?

Tags: discussion, architecture

How does stack overflow generate user ids?

Judging by the number of digits in ids, it seems they have more than a million users.

How do they handle id collisions?

Comment: The same way *databases* handle generating IDs, because that's exactly what is happening here; the SQL Server database provides that ID. Yes, there are millions of users, nearly 7.5 million accounts created and counting.

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309146/why-are-user-links-stackoverflow-com-users-id-username and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295188/why-are-there-no-users-with-id-6-17

Comment: MSE related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40767/random-noticing-of-user-account-numbers/40775#40775 and this blog might be interesting: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/

Comment: More than a million users? You should see what the questions table is like...

Answer (score 10):

They just use sequential ids. You can tell by checking the user with id of 1. It's not random. Now they probably wouldn't have to worry about collisions as long as the id sequence is determined in one server.

Comment: I guess StackOverflow's DB is distributed. How do they generate subsequent sequence numbers? Do they have one single instance hit by all clients? If so, couldn't this lead to a bottleneck if many clients request an ID at the same time? What do you think?

Comment: It's a bottleneck, but they can shard each table into it's own server and have read replicas, so the master server takes all the writes and the others handle reading which works great for this type of website because likely 99% of requests are reads.

Comment: So you say that they have a single "mega" master server which accepts all the writes and then they shard/divide and replicate the written data across several shards so that each shards servers only a portion of the whole data? If so, does it mean that the master DB server has a questions/answers table of billions of records?

Comment: In the case that was a lot of records, in Stackoverflow case turns out a single server and standby replica can handle everything: https://stackexchange.com/performance

Comment: I think you underestimate how much a giant bare metal optimized database server can take.

Comment: Where is this single giant master DB server mentioned at stackexchange.com/performance? Is it this beast here in the `4 SQL Servers` section: Stack Overflow -> RAM: 1.5 TB • DB size: 2.8 TB? Thank you!